# Creating a HTML table with Python with multiple columns

Tags: python, html, css

I have three lists and would like to write them into a html file to create a table.
My input are:
[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYlaa.png)

I expect the output is a table like this : 
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wWmI.png)

I already tried:

```
partie_split[i] = '<table > <tr>' + '<td>'+list10 +'</td>'+ '<td>'+ list11 +'</td>' + '<td>'+ list12  +'</td>'+' </tr> </table>
```

Comment: Would you know how to create the HTML manually (without Python)? If not, I suggest reading about [HTML tables](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp)

Comment: Thank you but i need to create with HTML manually using python

Answer (score 2):

In my knowledge, this can be the solution

```py
import HTML
table_data = [
        ['Last name',   'First name',   'Age'],
        ['Smith',       'John',         30],
        ['Carpenter',   'Jack',         47],
        ['Johnson',     'Paul',         62],
    ]
htmlcode = HTML.table(table_data)
print htmlcode
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string formatting:

```
data = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
t = '<table>\n{}\n</table>'.format('\n'.join('<tr>\n{}</tr>'.format('\n'.join(f'<td>{i}</td>' for i in b)) for b in data))
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>4</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>6</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>7</td>
<td>8</td>
<td>9</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks,  but the 3 lists are of strings !

Comment: @souhirdbira Please post your input with your desired output.

Comment: i post it now the input and the output expected

Comment: @souhirdbira Sorry for the delayed response. Can you format your input as text in your post, not an image? It is much easier to test my solution with your input formatted as text, rather than deducing it from an image.